# Property stays undefined after axios.post

Tags: reactjs, database, api, axios

i have a simple code:

```
 const ratingHandler1 = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 1 });
    console.log(props);
  };
```

It rates a book on button click. Although i see the value being added on Postgree database, using this console.log I can see in browser, that the property stays undefined. Anyone knows why?

Whole code of this component:

```
import classes from "./HighligtedBook.module.scss";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
const axios = require("axios");
const HighlightedBook = (props) => {
  const removeHanlder = () => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}`);
    alert("Książka usunięta");
  };
  const ratingHandler5 = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 5 });
  };
  const ratingHandler4 = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 4 });
  };
  const ratingHandler3 = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 3 });
  };
  const ratingHandler2 = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, { score: 2 });
  };
  const ratingHandler1 = () => {
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/book/${props.id}/rate`, {
      score: 1,
    });
    console.log(props);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.item}>
      <div className={classes.image}>
        <img src={props.image_url} alt={props.title} />
      </div>
      <div className={classes.content}>
        <h3 className={classes.title}> {props.title}</h3>
        <h4> {props.author}</h4>
        <h4> {props.release_date}</h4>
        <h4> {props.genre}</h4>
        <p className={classes.opis}>Opis: {props.description}</p>
        <div className={classes.actions}>
          <button onClick={ratingHandler5}>Oceń na 5</button>
          <button onClick={ratingHandler4}>Oceń na 4</button>
          <button onClick={ratingHandler3}>Oceń na 3</button>
          <button onClick={ratingHandler2}>Oceń na 2</button>
          <button onClick={ratingHandler1}>Oceń na 1 </button>
          <button onClick={removeHanlder}>Usuń</button>
          <Link to={`/edit-book/${props.id}`}>
            <button>Edytuj</button>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default HighlightedBook;
```

Comment: Can you include some more code for this question. Its hard to debug without seeing more context to what is going on

Comment: Well, i dont really know what i can add. Everythings work great exepct adding score. Basically i have a form in which i add a new book. I dont specify a score when adding a book, im doing in later in when the book is already added. And i was trying to do this with this simple code, but for some reasone its added to postgree, but not in the app

Comment: Let's start with your entire component which include this piece of code

Comment: Okay, i added :)

Comment: Is there some code somewhere that is supposed to update the props sent to this component that you are trying to log from the render cycle before there's been a chance to update and pass in the next render cycle? In other words, where is the code that updates the props, and why do you expect it to be updated immediately? Your console log is only ever going to log values from the current render cycle.

Comment: @qweqweqweqweqweq that is strange because React's props never is undefined. If no prop is passed the props object would be an empty one. Are you sure to describe it right?

Answer (score 0):

From what you had poorly described. Your problem might be this:

Your API works well. It just does its job. So does your frontend. It's what you coded doesn't serve the purpose you desired. You need to add a callback to your `axios` post function to read the new score from Postgres after the request is succeeded. That callback will call to state hook to update the score being shown  in client's browser. The frontend just doesn't update itself unless you tell it to